# Isomorphism of product of local ring of variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is a proposition given in *Fulton - Algebraic curves, section 2.9*

Let $I$ be an ideal in $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ ($k$ : Alg. closed field) and suppose corresponding variety $V(I)$ is finite. Then there exists an isomorphism $$k[x_1,\cdots,x_n ]/I \cong \prod_{p\in V}\mathcal{O}_p(V) $$
where $\mathcal{O}_p(V)$ is a local ring of $V$ at $p$.

Since this book doesn't require the commutative-algebraic theorem, the proof is more or less elementary. However I already know the theorem,

If $M$ is finite length $R$-module with $0=M_0 \subset M_1 \subset \cdots \subset M_n =M$ a composition series such that $M_i/M_{i-1} \cong R/P_i$ (so $P_i$ is maximal in $R$) then there exists an isomorphism $M \cong \prod_iM_{P_i}$.  I really think the above theorem comes from this theorem, but I can't show this directly when the case $I$ is not radical ideal.

If $I$ is radical ideal, $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/I=\Gamma(V)$ is just a coordinate ring with finitely many maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_1,\cdots,\mathfrak{m}_n$ (since there is one to one correspondence between points and maximal ideal). Then we can find the composition series

$$0=\mathfrak{m}_1\cdots \mathfrak{m}_n \subset \cdots \subset \mathfrak{m}_1 \subset \Gamma(V) $$. And in this case $0=\mathfrak{m}_1\cdots \mathfrak{m}_n$ is because $\Gamma(V)$ is nilpotent-free ($\because$ $I$ is radical) and by the CRT, the product of maximal ideals is just  set of nilpotent.

Can this argument extended to non-radical ideal $I$?

Answer (score 1):

The statement you want to prove is wrong: the left-hand side is reduced (i.e. is free of nilpotents) if and only if $I$ is a radical ideal. The right-hand side however is always reduced, because local rings of algebraic varieties are reduced.

Actually Fulton (Proposition 6, Section 2.9) states something else: instead of the local rings $O_p(V)$ he takes the local rings $O_p(\mathbb{A}^n)/IO_p(\mathbb{A}^n)$, where $\mathbb{A}^n$ is the affine space of dimension $n$ over $k$.